# libinput in a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, input, raspberry-pi3

Question related to my previous post "[No input enabled while running QT app in docker container on Raspberry PI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50732166/no-input-enabled-while-running-qt-app-in-docker-container-on-raspberry-pi)": seems that there is a problem with libinput in a docker container (Ubuntu 16.04) running on Raspberry Pi 3 (Ubuntu Mate): libinput-list-devices returns nothing when I run it in a container while it returns correct devices when I run on RP3 itself.  I am pretty new to UI on Linux, so may be missing some simple things – any help is appreciated.

Comment: There does not seem to be a question here. What is the question?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response jww - I was on a trip.  The question was why libinput-list-devices returns nothing in a container and how to fix it.  Explanation and  solution suggested by larsks works - confirmed.  The tricky part was "-v /run/udev/data:/run/udev/data" - I was not able to google it :)

Answer (score 6):

A Docker container does not, by default, have access to any host devices.  Libinput is telling you the truth -- the container is unable to see any of the input devices attached to your host.

You can expose specific devices to your container using the `--device` argument to `docker run`.  You can expose *all* the devices on your host using the `--privileged` flag, which disables most of the protections that Docker puts in place (i.e., it should be used with caution).

For example, on my host I have:

```
# ls /
by-id    event0  event10  event12  event14  event16  event3  event5  event7  event9  mouse0
by-path  event1  event11  event13  event15  event2   event4  event6  event8  mice
```

If I start a normal container, none of these devices are visible:

```
# docker run -it --rm fedora bash
[root@9582799320ff /]# ls /dev/input
ls: cannot access '/dev/input': No such file or directory
```

But if I expose that device to the container:

```
# docker run -it --rm --device /dev/input/event3 fedora bash
```

I see:

```
[root@bcca19a2341b /]# ls /dev/input/
event3
```

And I can open and interact with that device.

Note that even when exposing an input device like this, discovery
(e.g., `libinput list-devices`) won't work without additional
configuration.  The `libput list-devices` command relies on
information in `/run/udev/data`, which isn't exposed inside the
container by default.  You can expose that using the `-v` argument to
`docker run`:

```
# docker run -it --rm --device /dev/input/event3 \
  -v /run/udev/data:/run/udev/data fedora bash
```

And now discovery works:

```
[root@e897d760a147 /]# libinput list-devices
Device:           daskeyboard
Kernel:           /dev/input/event3
Group:            1
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer.

Comment: Thank you one more time Lars (just guessing the name :) - it works just fine, confirmed.

Comment: this worked for me but only if the keyboard was already plugged in at the time the container started. Once I disconnected the keyboard and reconnected it, it wouldn't work and `libinput list-devices` would say "Failed to open /dev/input/event0 (No such device)". What worked for me in the end was to mount the whole /run/udev instead.